# class ListElement for creating an easy list with next pointers -> "does not name a type" - error

Tags: c++, linked-list, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma once

class ListElement
{

public:
    ListElement(T* d)
    {
        next = NULL;
        data = d;
    }

    T* getData(void) {return data;}
    void setNext(ListElement* n) {next = n;}
    ListElement* getNext(void) {return next;}

private:
    T* data;
    ListElement* next;


};
```

Our teacher said, that we shouldnt think about the T* ... but this T* is making huge problems. I dont want to create many different list classes for every type...

CMD-Error
ListClass.h:9:15: error: expected ')' before '*' token
9 |  ListElement(T* d)
|             ~ ^
|               )
ListClass.h:15:2: error: 'T' does not name a type
15 |  T* getData(void) {return data;}
|  ^
ListClass.h:20:2: error: 'T' does not name a type
20 |  T* data;
|  ^

Comment: You didn't define T. If you wan't a list of any type you have to create a wrapper around `void*`. Standard components already may have such - `std::any`, you want something similar.

Comment: *I dont want to create many different list classes for every type...* -- Did your teacher discuss what a `template` is?  If so, you forgot `template <typename T>` above the `class ListElement` line.